# Pyinstaller creates executable that requires administrator

Tags: python

I am trying to package a python script into an executable. The executable name has the word 'update' in its name, and the resulting executable requires UAC elavation.
I have a manifest file I tried to get pyinstaller to generate a normal executable, but it does not work.

This is the manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity name="firmware_updater" processorArchitecture="amd64" type="win32" version="1.0.0.0"/>
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity language="*" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" type="win32" version="6.0.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
      <security>
          <requestedPrivileges>
              <requestedExecutionLevel
                  level="asInvoker"
                  uiAccess="false"
              />  
          </requestedPrivileges>
      </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <asmv3:application xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
      <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
  </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

and the command I use for pyinstaller is:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon .\<filename>.ico --manifest .\<filename>.exe.manifest --exclude-module tkinter --exclude-module IPython .\<filename>.py
```

The manifest file is in the same directory as the python script.

I am using Python 2.7.16 and Pyinstaller 3.4.

How can I get pyinstaller to generate an executable that does not require elavation?

Comment: Resolved using the solution found here: [How do you add a manifest to Pyinstaller compiled EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823824/how-do-you-add-a-manifest-to-pyinstaller-compiled-exe)